# Random User Generator API - get user by ID Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular, but managed to make an Ajax-call and print out users from *Random User Generator API* in a list view.
Now I want to make a detailed view while clicked on a user.
In my HTML I make a function call: fetchInfoById(user.id.value)
In my script the function:

```
$scope.fetchInfoById = function(info_id) {     
   $http.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?id.value="+info_id)
   //also tried:   $http.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?id/value="+info_id)
          .success(function(data) {
            $scope.oneUserResult = data.results; 
    }); 
}
```

It does give me a user to a detail view, but not the chosen one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your API call  is going to return you a random user every time you call it. You might be better off capturing your entire list and caching it in memory and then accessing it rather than trying to make a live API call each time.

Comment: you need to format your request URL like this: https://randomuser.me/api/?id=info_id

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your good suggestions. 
I know it is a random generator, but setting parameters for the request to: "seed=...", the same persons is displayed on each listview request:

```
$http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=15&seed=abc&inc=gender,name,location,email,dob,phone,cell,id,picture,info,nat&nat=gb')
    .success(function(response){
        $scope.userResult = response.results; 
});
```

Then I fetched the id for each person and passed in as a parameter to the function call for the request for the detail view.

I tried with console.log() to make sure I passed in the right value for the detail view request and then even hardcoded the 
parameter for the request ie:

```
$scope.getInfoById = function(info_id) {    
    console.log("from HTML: "+info_id.value );   //  =  JK 00 46 67 
    $http.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?id="+'JK 00 46 67 H')    ...
```

The jason data behind the API  is formatted like this for the id-property:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
     "id": {
        "name": "BSN",
        "value": "04242023"
     },...
```

I still haven't figured out how to get the one user by id. Getting different users all the time, even with hard coded id...
Instead of making the second request my solution was to a pass the "clicked user" as a parameter for the detailed view.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
$scope.fetchInfoById = function(info_id) {     
   $http.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?id="+info_id)
   //also tried:   $http.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?id/value="+info_id)
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.oneUserResult = data.results; 
   }); 
}
```

Also, make sure you are passing in the correct value to this function.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch a list of users from API call "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5".

```
$scope.getAllUsers= function(resultCount) {     
       $http.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results="+resultCount)
            .success(function(data) {
            $scope.users= data.results; 
   });
```

Display them on the screen.

On click of one record fetch details for that particular record from users list fetched earlier.

```
$scope.getUserById= function(userId) {
    return $scope.users.filter(function(user) {
      return user.id.value=== userId;
    })[0]; // apply necessary null / undefined checks wherever required. 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

another way using ng-model:

```
$scope.user = {};
$scope.fetchInfoById = function() {     
   $http.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?id="$scope.user.id)
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.oneUserResult = data.results; 
   }); 
}
```